# Object not being saved in Celery task

Tags: django, django-models, celery

I am using `celery=4.3` Django package and Django 2.2.6.

I noticed that object is not saved when I try to update it from celery task function

```
@app.task
def update_object(object_id, points):
    object = MyObject.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    object.update_points(points)
```

My object looks like this:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    ....

    def update_points(self, points):
        self.points += points
        self.save()
```

I am calling celery task with:
`update_object.delay(object_id, points)`

And this doesn't work :/ Does anyone have some suggestion why?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `update_object.delay((object_id, points))`, with the params as tuple.
Normally, you need pass *args, and **kwargs ([see this doc](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html))

Quick Cheat Sheet

```
T.delay(arg, kwarg=value)
    Star arguments shortcut to .apply_async. (.delay(*args, **kwargs) calls .apply_async(args, kwargs)).

T.apply_async((arg,), {'kwarg': value})

T.apply_async(countdown=10)
    executes in 10 seconds from now.

T.apply_async(eta=now + timedelta(seconds=10))
    executes in 10 seconds from now, specified using eta

T.apply_async(countdown=60, expires=120)
    executes in one minute from now, but expires after 2 minutes.

T.apply_async(expires=now + timedelta(days=2))
    expires in 2 days, set using datetime.
```

Comment: This is what it says further down the page `task.delay(arg1, arg2, kwarg1='x', kwarg2='y')`